# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-community_toolbar-android:compileDebugAidl'

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, gradle-dependencies

I'm upgrading this two repositories gradle versions and Android SDK API level version to the latest one.

- https://github.com/jsierles/react-native-audio

  - Gradle version: 3.4.2 to 7.2.1
  - SDK ver: 28 (target & compile) | Tools: 28.0.3

    - To SDK ver: 33 and Tools: 33.0.0
- https://github.com/goodatlas/react-native-audio-record

  - No Gradle version registered
  - Compile SDK version: 27 | Target SDK ver: 26 | Build tools: 27.0.3

    - To SDK ver: 33 and Tools: 33.0.0
- https://github.com/ouarrtaha/react-native-voice-changer

  - Gradle version: 3.4.1 to 7.2.1
  - SDK ver: 28 (target & compile) | Tools: 28.0.3

    - To SDK ver: 33 and Tools: 33.0.0

I figured out most of the problems by simply using the same build.gradle for all of them:

```
def DEFAULT_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION = '33.0.0'
def DEFAULT_MIN_SDK_VERSION = 16
def DEFAULT_TARGET_SDK_VERSION = 33

def safeExtGet(prop, fallback) {
    rootProject.ext.has(prop) ? rootProject.ext.get(prop) : fallback
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

buildscript {
    // The Android Gradle plugin is only required when opening the android folder stand-alone.
    // This avoids unnecessary downloads and potential conflicts when the library is included as a
    // module dependency in an application project.
    // ref: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:build_script_external_dependencies
    if (project == rootProject) {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

android {
    compileSdkVersion safeExtGet('compileSdkVersion', DEFAULT_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion safeExtGet('buildToolsVersion', DEFAULT_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION)
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion safeExtGet('minSdkVersion', DEFAULT_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
        targetSdkVersion safeExtGet('targetSdkVersion', DEFAULT_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

repositories {
    // ref: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-local-repository
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
    maven {
        // Android JSC is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist"
    }
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'  // From node_modules
}
```

But I used this one from my demo app.

#### android/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

buildscript {
    ext {
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        buildToolsVersion = '33.0.0'
        minSdkVersion = 26
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        // versionCode = 1
        // versionName = '1.0'

        if (System.properties['os.arch'] == 'aarch64') {
            // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
            ndkVersion = '24.0.8215888'
        } else {
            // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
            ndkVersion = '21.4.7075529'
        }
    }

        repositories {
            // google()
            // jcenter()
            // ref: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-local-repository
            mavenLocal()
            mavenCentral()
            maven {
                // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
                url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
            }
            maven {
                // Android JSC is installed from npm
                url "$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist"
            }
            mavenCentral {
                // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
                // older versions over there.
                content {
                    excludeGroup 'com.facebook.react'
                }
            }
            google()
            maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
        // implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
        }
}

// dependencies {
//     implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
//     implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
//     implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
//     implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
// }

// apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
// apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

android {
    compileSdkVersion = 33
    buildToolsVersion = '33.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion = 26
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

// repositories {
//     // ref: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-local-repository
//     mavenLocal()
//     mavenCentral()
//     maven {
//         // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
//         url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
//     }
//     maven {
//         // Android JSC is installed from npm
//         url "$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist"
//     }
//     // mavenCentral {
//     //     // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
//     //     // older versions over there.
//     //     content {
//     //         excludeGroup 'com.facebook.react'
//     //     }
//     // }
//     google()
//     maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
//     jcenter()
// }

// dependencies {
//     //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
//     implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
// }

def configureReactNativePom(def pom) {
    def packageJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(file('../package.json').text)

    pom.project {
        name packageJson.title
        artifactId packageJson.name
        version = packageJson.version
        group = 'com.reactlibrary'
        description packageJson.description
        url packageJson.repository.baseUrl

        licenses {
            license {
                name packageJson.license
                url packageJson.repository.baseUrl + '/blob/master/' + packageJson.licenseFilename
                distribution 'repo'
            }
        }

        developers {
            developer {
                id packageJson.author.username
                name packageJson.author.name
            }
        }
    }
}

afterEvaluate { project ->
    // some Gradle build hooks ref:
    // https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/gradle-beyond-the/9781449373801/ch03.html
    task androidJavadoc(type: Javadoc) {
        source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
        classpath += files(android.bootClasspath)
        // classpath += files(project.getConfigurations().getByName('compile').asList())
        include '**/*.java'
    }

    task androidJavadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadoc) {
        classifier = 'javadoc'
        from androidJavadoc.destinationDir
    }

    task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
        classifier = 'sources'
        from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
        include '**/*.java'
    }

    android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        def name = variant.name.capitalize()
        def javaCompileTask = variant.javaCompileProvider.get()

        task "jar${name}"(type: Jar, dependsOn: javaCompileTask) {
            from javaCompileTask.destinationDir
        }
    }

    artifacts {
        archives androidSourcesJar
        archives androidJavadocJar
    }
}

subprojects { subproject ->
        if (project['name'] == 'react-native-voice-changer') {
        project.configurations { compile { } }
        }
}
```

#### android/app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

import com.android.build.OutputFile
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
 *   // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
 *   // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: '../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle'

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and that value will be read here. If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get('enableHermes', false)

/**
 * Architectures to build native code for.
 */
def reactNativeArchitectures() {
    def value = project.getProperties().get('reactNativeArchitectures')
    return value ? value.split(',') : ['armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'x86_64', 'arm64-v8a']
}

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.rndiffapp'
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED', isNewArchitectureEnabled().toString()

        if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
            // We configure the CMake build only if you decide to opt-in for the New Architecture.
            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    arguments "-DPROJECT_BUILD_DIR=$buildDir",
                        "-DREACT_ANDROID_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid",
                        "-DREACT_ANDROID_BUILD_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/build",
                        "-DNODE_MODULES_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules",
                        '-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared'
                }
            }
            if (!enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture) {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters(*reactNativeArchitectures())
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
        // We configure the NDK build only if you decide to opt-in for the New Architecture.
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                path "$projectDir/src/main/jni/CMakeLists.txt"
            }
        }
        def reactAndroidProjectDir = project(':ReactAndroid').projectDir
        def packageReactNdkDebugLibs = tasks.register('packageReactNdkDebugLibs', Copy) {
            dependsOn(':ReactAndroid:packageReactNdkDebugLibsForBuck')
            from("$reactAndroidProjectDir/src/main/jni/prebuilt/lib")
            into("$buildDir/react-ndk/exported")
        }
        def packageReactNdkReleaseLibs = tasks.register('packageReactNdkReleaseLibs', Copy) {
            dependsOn(':ReactAndroid:packageReactNdkReleaseLibsForBuck')
            from("$reactAndroidProjectDir/src/main/jni/prebuilt/lib")
            into("$buildDir/react-ndk/exported")
        }
        afterEvaluate {
            // If you wish to add a custom TurboModule or component locally,
            // you should uncomment this line.
            // preBuild.dependsOn("generateCodegenArtifactsFromSchema")
            preDebugBuild.dependsOn(packageReactNdkDebugLibs)
            preReleaseBuild.dependsOn(packageReactNdkReleaseLibs)

            // Due to a bug inside AGP, we have to explicitly set a dependency
            // between configureCMakeDebug* tasks and the preBuild tasks.
            // This can be removed once this is solved: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/207403732
            configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo.dependsOn(preReleaseBuild)
            configureCMakeDebug.dependsOn(preDebugBuild)
            reactNativeArchitectures().each { architecture ->
                tasks.findByName("configureCMakeDebug[${architecture}]")?.configure {
                    dependsOn('preDebugBuild')
                }
                tasks.findByName("configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo[${architecture}]")?.configure {
                    dependsOn('preReleaseBuild')
                }
            }
        }
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include(*reactNativeArchitectures())
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            // Example: versionCode 1 will generate 1001 for armeabi-v7a, 1002 for x86, etc.
            def versionCodes = ['armeabi-v7a': 1, 'x86': 2, 'arm64-v8a': 3, 'x86_64': 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }
        }
    }
}

// buildscript {
//     repositories {
//             // google()
//             // jcenter()
//             // ref: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-local-repository
//             maven {
//                 // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
//                 url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
//             }
//             maven {
//                 // Android JSC is installed from npm
//                 url "$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist"
//             }
//             // mavenCentral {
//             //     // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
//             //     // older versions over there.
//             //     content {
//             //         excludeGroup 'com.facebook.react'
//             //     }
//             // }
//             google()
//             mavenLocal()
//             mavenCentral()
//             maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
//             jcenter()
//     }
// }

allprojects {
    repositories {
            // google()
            // jcenter()
            // ref: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-local-repository
            maven {
                // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
                url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
            }
            maven {
                // Android JSC is installed from npm
                url "$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist"
            }
            // mavenCentral {
            //     // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            //     // older versions over there.
            //     content {
            //         excludeGroup 'com.facebook.react'
            //     }
            // }
            google()
            mavenLocal()
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
            jcenter()
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    // implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    // implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'  // From node_modules

    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0'

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
        implementation('com.facebook.react:hermes-engine:+') { // From node_modules
            exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
        }
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
    // If new architecture is enabled, we let you build RN from source
    // Otherwise we fallback to a prebuilt .aar bundled in the NPM package.
    // This will be applied to all the imported transtitive dependency.
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
            substitute(module('com.facebook.react:react-native'))
                    .using(project(':ReactAndroid'))
                    .because("On New Architecture we're building React Native from source")
            substitute(module('com.facebook.react:hermes-engine'))
                    .using(project(':ReactAndroid:hermes-engine'))
                    .because("On New Architecture we're building Hermes from source")
        }
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.implementation
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file('../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle'); 
applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

def isNewArchitectureEnabled() {
    // To opt-in for the New Architecture, you can either:
    // - Set `newArchEnabled` to true inside the `gradle.properties` file
    // - Invoke gradle with `-newArchEnabled=true`
    // - Set an environment variable `ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_newArchEnabled=true`
    return project.hasProperty('newArchEnabled') && project.newArchEnabled == 'true'
}
```

All this two gradles comes from the example of `react-native-voice-changer`:

- https://github.com/ouarrtaha/react-native-voice-changer/tree/master/example
- https://github.com/ouarrtaha/react-native-voice-changer/blob/master/example/android/build.gradle

  - Gradle version: 3.4.2 to 7.2.1
  - SDK ver: 28 (target & compile) | Tools: 28.0.3

    - To SDK ver: 33 and Tools: 33.0.0
- https://github.com/ouarrtaha/react-native-voice-changer/blob/master/example/android/app/build.gradle

  - No grandle version referenced and the SDK API level version is inherited from rootProject

## The problem:

I cannot manage to solve this issue:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-community_toolbar-android:compileDebugAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':react-native-community_toolbar-android:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-community_toolbar-android > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1
   > Could not find androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-community_toolbar-android > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1
   > Could not find androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-community_toolbar-android > com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline:0.8.1
         project :react-native-community_toolbar-android > com.facebook.fresco:drawee:0.8.1
```

I'm unsure where does this error comes from, so if you need that I submit more files just tell me.